# Separating code for QRcode image generator Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

When I tested the code only on HTML it worked just fine, but when I separate it doesn't show -surprise - here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img id='qrcode' src=''>
<button onclick="newQR()">Gerar QRcode</button>
<script>
  function newQR() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99) + 1);
    document.getElementById('qrcode').src = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=" + x
  }
  newQR()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I want to separate them, for example, having the function newQR inside script.js and the rest inside index.html, like this:

```
 script.js
    function newQR() {
    var x = (Math.random() * 99999999999999999);
    document.getElementById('qrcode').src ="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=" + x
    return 
  }
```

index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
 <button onclick="newQR()">Gerar QRcode</button>
   <img = 'qrcode' />
    <script type="js/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: it's working on my editor. Also, calling "newQR()" after the function is redundant.

Comment: It works, but I can't separate, leaving a HTML file alone just showing the button and the image that will be generated and and JS file with the function code.

Comment: have you created your javascript file? if yes show us the code within that file.

Comment: Yes, I edited the question, sorry for not being more specific,

Comment: Could it be that you forgot the "id" tag on the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem could simply be that you've forgotten the `id` attribute within this line of your `HTML` `<img = 'qrcode' />`

Try changing that to this: `<img id='qrcode' src=''>`

However, if after trying... the problem at hand still persists then I'd recommend you to try the examples below.

Change your `HTML` markup to this:

```
<body>
  <img id='qrcode' src=''>
  <button id="Btn">Gerar QRcode</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Within your `javascript` file simply implement this:

```
document.getElementById("Btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var x = (Math.random() * 99999999999999999);
    document.getElementById('qrcode').src ="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=" + x;
});
```

or this version of javascript if you prefer:

```
document.getElementById("Btn").addEventListener("click", newQR);

function newQR() {
   var x = (Math.random() * 99999999999999999);
   document.getElementById('qrcode').src ="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=" + x;
}
```

Comment: Eduarda Buss has submitted this question twice but with the changes you have suggested but hasn't marked any answer from this posts so I wouldn't waste much more time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42823679/separating-javascript-code-of-my-html-page

Comment: @NewToJS I see so OP has posted the question multiple times across the site. Anyway, thanks for the recommendation and just to note, the link you've provided me  is not what I've recommended to OP.

Comment: NewtoJS that wasn't me, it was my coworker. We are having the same problems, and he insisted on asking twice. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing right now is the order of reference js files which must be placed in-order. The first js file you need to attach is the QR js file and then, your own script.

By the way, it is always recommended to have your your js files appended at the body tag. By the way, here is another tip that you should be knowing that you need to ensure that all dom elements have been loaded by simply putting your js methods in a simple block:

```
(function() {
 // You are ensuring that the page is loaded completely.
  newQR();
})();
```

Here is the sample HTML code:

```js
//// my myownsrc.js
function newQR() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99) + 1);
    document.getElementById('qrcode').src = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=" + x
  }
   (function() {
   // You are ensuring that the page is loaded completely.
   newQR();

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img id='qrcode' src=''>
<button onclick="newQR()">Gerar QRcode</button>
<script src="qrimage.js"></script>
<script src="myownsrc.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```