# Separating javascript code of my html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <img id='qrcode' src=''>
   <button onclick="newQR()">Gerar QRcode</button>
   <script>  function newQR() {
   var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999999999999999) + 1);
   document.getElementById('qrcode').src = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=" + x + "&size=[500]x[500]&ecc=L&qzone=4&format=png";
 }
   </script>
    </body>
```

Now I am trying to divide creating a js file and putting the script code inside.
Right now my code is:

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <img id='qrcode' src=''>
  <button onclick="newQR()">Gerar QRcode</button>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript file (that it is inside a paste called js)

```
  function newQR() {
   var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999999999999999) + 1);
   document.getElementById('qrcode').src = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=" + x + "&size=[500]x[500]&ecc=L&qzone=4&format=png";
 }
```

Why it is not working anymore?

Comment: Open your browser console and check for errors...

Comment: Why have you submitted this question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42823565/separating-code-for-qrcode-image-generator-javascript-html

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it is because you link your javascript file after you have the function called. I would rather have the javascript reference in the head.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <img id='qrcode' src=''>
  <button onclick="newQR()">Gerar QRcode</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is linked relatively instead of absolutely:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/script.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "/js/script.js"></script>
```

Verify that your JS is viewable in the browser by navigating to `/js/script.js`. If it's still not working, check your console for errors (right click > inspect element)